# Proxy does not accept offered credentials. C# remoting

Tags: c#, proxy, remoting

I'm having trouble with a proxy server which won't accept the authentication details my application is offering it. Here is what I'm doing:

```
    private bool DoLoginTest(WebProxy wp = null)
    {
        if(MMremotingClient.LoginWCP(wp) == AdminNetworkFlags.CLIENTPOS)
        {
            FL.Log("Test licensing server connection REM finished");
            FL.Log("Connection could be established successfully");

            MMremotingClient.DoTask(BitConverter.GetBytes((int)AdminNetworkFlags.CLIENTEND), "Nothing");
            MMremotingClient.DisableFLogging();
            Invoke(txtDelegate, " finished\r\n");
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            FL.Log("Test server connection failed!");
            FL.Log("NoTask");
            Invoke(txtDelegate, " failed\r\n");
            Invoke(MBDelegate, "Could not reach the licencing server. Please make sure that no firewall is blocking port 80, or that your computer is allowed to access the internet.");
            return false;
        }
    }
```

In a series of tests, i try to connect to a server with the old remoting protocol (upgrade to WCF not possible atm). If the DoLoginTest Method fails, the user will see a little form where he can enter the proxy details which get injected into the HTTPClientChannel object. Then another try to connect to the Server is made.

```
    public static AdminNetworkFlags LoginWCP(WebProxy wProx = null)
    {
        FileLogger.Log("MMLC: LoginWCP");
        Register(wProx);
        return Login();
    }

    private static void Register(WebProxy iwp = null)
    {
        FileLogger.Log("MMLC: Register");
        try
        {
            IDictionary props = new Hashtable();

            if(iwp == null)
            {
                props["useDefaultCredentials"] = true;
            }
            else
            {
                NetworkCredential nc = (NetworkCredential)iwp.Credentials;
                if(nc != null)
                {
                    props["domain"] = nc.Domain ?? null;
                    props["password"] = nc.Password;
                    props["username"] = nc.UserName;
                    props["useDefaultCredentials"] = false;
                }
                else
                {
                    props["domain"] = null;
                    props["password"] = "1234";
                    props["username"] = "u.name";
                    props["useDefaultCredentials"] = false;
                }
            }
            ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = false;
            HttpChan = new HttpClientChannel(props, new BinaryClientFormatterSinkProvider());
            SetChannelProxy(HttpChan, iwp ?? WebRequest.GetSystemWebProxy());
            FileLogger.Log("MMLC: RegChannel");
            ChannelServices.RegisterChannel(HttpChan, true);
            RemoteObject = (IRemObject)Activator.GetObject(typeof(IRemObject), "http://someAdress:80/IRemObject");
            FileLogger.Log("MMLC: connected");
        }
        catch(Exception x)
        {
            Trace.WriteLine("Error connecting to remote server, reason: " + x.Message);
            RemoteObject = null;
        }
    }

    private static void SetChannelProxy(HttpClientChannel channel, IWebProxy proxy)
    {
        FieldInfo proxyObjectFieldInfo = typeof(HttpClientChannel).GetField("_proxyObject", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
        proxyObjectFieldInfo.SetValue(channel, proxy);
    }
```

This is the Form asking the user for Proxy details. If the User ends it with hitting the "OK" button on it, the defined Proxy property is set. That property is then passed to the LoginWCP() function.

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        definedProxy = new WebProxy(txtAdress.Text, decimal.ToInt32(nudPort.Value));
        Address = txtAdress.Text;
        Port = decimal.ToInt32(nudPort.Value);
        NetworkCredential nc = new NetworkCredential()
        {
            Domain = string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(txtDomain.Text) ? null : txtDomain.Text,
            UserName = txtName.Text,
            Password = txtPassword.Text
        };
        definedProxy.Credentials = nc;
        DialogResult = System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK;
        Close();
    }
```

So far this worked fine, but now I have the first user with an proxy in an Active Directory Environment. As i am lacking an AD, i cannot test the application in it. So I am asking you, is there anything wrong with my application? Do i need to check the user ipnut for something? is the `Expect100Continue = false`doing something bad?

Comment: I hate bumping but I just need to, as this problem occured again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, this thing happened again, but this time it could be solved. First I have to name the culprit giving me a hard time. ZScaler. This software suite build around blocking and sniffing into connections from the outside and inside seems to only allow connections to adresses, and not direct IPs. Up to this point my application directly connected to an IP, instead of an real adress. Some Changes later, my server is now browsable by an address, and the application is let through by the proxy of the ZScaler.